# pagination through Zend Paginator giving error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

i am using zend paginator for pagination in my app here is the action that is doing so

```
public function listAction(){
      $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();  
      $DB = $registry['DB'];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `task` ORDER BY task_name ASC";
      $result = $DB->fetchAll($sql);
      $page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
      $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result);
      $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(3);
      $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
      $this->view->paginator=$paginator;
  }
```

and this is the view for this action

```
 <table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
  <th>Task Name</th>      
  <th>Task Assign To</th>  
  <th>Action</th>     
</tr>
   <?php
    foreach($this->paginator as $record){ ?>
    <tr> 
   <td><?php echo $record['task_name']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $record['task_assign']?></td>  

  <td>
    <a href="edit/id/<?php echo $record['id']?>">Edit</a>
    |
    <a href="del/id/<?php echo $record['id']?>">Delete</a>      
  </td>   
</tr> 
   <?php } ?>
  </table>
   <?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'pagination.phtml'); ?>
```

by doing so it giving me this error

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend_login\application\views\scripts\task\list.phtml on line 47
```

line 47 refers to

```
 <td><?php echo $record['task_name']?></td>
```

than i used this function to convert object to array

```
function objectToArray( $object ){
 if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) ){
  return $object;}
 if( is_object( $object ) ){
 $object = get_object_vars( $object );}
return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );}
$paginator = objectToArray($this->paginator);
```

now i change this in my code

```
foreach($paginator as $record){
```

and also this

```
   <?php echo $this->paginationControl($paginator, 'Sliding', 'pagination.phtml'); ?>
```

but its giving me this error now

```
 Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::paginationControl() must be an instance of Zend_Paginator, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend_login\library\Zend\View\Helper\PaginationControl.php on line 88
```

can you please tell what i am missing i am new to zend so please dont mind my awkward question
**this is my ErrorController.php**

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
public function errorAction()
{
    $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

    switch ($errors->type) {
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:

            // 404 error -- controller or action not found
            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
            $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
            break;
        default:
            // application error
            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
            $this->view->message = 'Application error';
            break;
    }

    // Log exception, if logger available
    if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
        $log->crit($this->view->message, $errors->exception);
    }

    // conditionally display exceptions
    if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {
        $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
    }

    $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
}

public function getLog()
{
    $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
    if (!$bootstrap->hasPluginResource('Log')) {
        return false;
    }
    $log = $bootstrap->getResource('Log');
    return $log;
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of running the `$record` through your `objectToArray()` function - where I imagine the problem to be - couldn't you just access the values as `$record->task_name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call it as an object:

```
<td><?php echo $record->task_name; ?></td>
```

UPDATE: all other errors resolved in chat

Comment: not working i did so but now giving me this error Fatal error: Call to a member function hasPluginResource() on a non-object in application\controllers\ErrorController.php on line 67. i think i m doing something wrong which i dont know what its

Comment: Did you remove this line? It's not needed here - $paginator = objectToArray($this->paginator);

Comment: How does your ErrorController look like?

Comment: i am editing my answer and in the last there it is kindly see it

Comment: It cannot find your bootstrap. Do you use bootstrapping at all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6684/discussion-between-bartekr-and-shaheenbarki)

Comment: how to use that i will be very thankful if you please guide me.thanx in advance